# Box Api : Adding User Group as Collaborator return 403 Forbidden

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am trying to add collaborators through Box API, but when I am adding a user group, the api request return status 403: Forbidden.

Here is the request attributes i'm passing:

```
{"item": { "id": "3907701373", "type": "folder"}, "accessible_by": {"id": "400235","type":"group"}, "role": "viewer"}
```

And it returns me this error:

Bearer realm="Service", error="insufficient_scope", error_description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token."

Comment: Hi Nikko, did you see the follow-up I posted?

Comment: @JohnHoerr Thanks, also thought it has something to do with my user's access on the user group and folder that I am modifying. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for [Create Collaboration](https://box-content.readme.io/#add-a-collaboration) states that:

> Errors may occur if the IDs are invalid or *if the user does not have permissions to create a collaboration*.

Are you able to create a collaboration with a regular user on that folder?

**Follow-Up**

I think the problem could be due to one, or possibly both, of the following:

1. Box recently introduced the [Group Admin](https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/201142796-Admins-and-Co-admins-Overview-and-FAQs), which has permissions to "*add existing users to their groups, create new users that will be assigned to their groups, and assign folder access to their groups.*" You may need to have those permissions in order to manage group collaborations.
2. Your may need to enable the **Manage an Enterprise** scope for your application, under *OAuth2 Parameters* > *Scopes.* If (1) above is true then your app most likely requires elevated, enterprise privileges.

Comment: Yes, If it is of single user, the user is added on that folder.